# Could not load file Could not load client_secrets.json

Tags: java, inputstream, google-bigquery

I am new dev in BigQuery. I'm trying to access Big query from my application.

I just follow sample code available at BigQuery API Quickstart
[image]
My application throws nullpointerexception when application try to load "google client secrets" from JSON file.
[image]
I have placed the JSON file at root folder of the application.
However the result when running is "Could not load file load client_secrets.json

[image]

Please tell me the way to do it...

Comment: Your client secret path is wrong. You need to build your path using the current directory, and not references something with absolute path. You should not start with slash.

Answer (score 0):

We should use other code instead of getResourceAsStream 
[image]

[image]